# How to add a button to every row in Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm creating a virtualized table in react using Material-UI. In every last column of every row, there should be a button to extend that particular row. I understand how to do the extending of a row, but I have not managed to figure out how to add the buttons correctly.

I'm trying to integrate this in the example of virtualized tables provided by the documentation, the exact code is given below from: https://material-ui.com/components/tables/. However, as this example provides one generalized function to create all of the data cells and because I don't think I can access the index of a particular row, I cannot figure out how to add the actual buttons.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { AutoSizer, Column, Table } from 'react-virtualized';

const styles = theme => ({
  flexContainer: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    boxSizing: 'border-box',
  },
  tableRow: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
  },
  tableRowHover: {
    '&:hover': {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.grey[200],
    },
  },
  tableCell: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  noClick: {
    cursor: 'initial',
  },
});

class MuiVirtualizedTable extends React.PureComponent {
  static defaultProps = {
    headerHeight: 48,
    rowHeight: 48,
  };

  getRowClassName = ({ index }) => {
    const { classes, onRowClick } = this.props;

    return clsx(classes.tableRow, classes.flexContainer, {
      [classes.tableRowHover]: index !== -1 && onRowClick != null,
    });
  };

  cellRenderer = ({ cellData, columnIndex }) => {
    const { columns, classes, rowHeight, onRowClick } = this.props;
    return (
      <TableCell
        component="div"
        className={clsx(classes.tableCell, classes.flexContainer, {
          [classes.noClick]: onRowClick == null,
        })}
        variant="body"
        style={{ height: rowHeight }}
        align={(columnIndex != null && columns[columnIndex].numeric) || false ? 'right' : 'left'}
      >
        {cellData}
      </TableCell>
    );
  };

  headerRenderer = ({ label, columnIndex }) => {
    const { headerHeight, columns, classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <TableCell
        component="div"
        className={clsx(classes.tableCell, classes.flexContainer, classes.noClick)}
        variant="head"
        style={{ height: headerHeight }}
        align={columns[columnIndex].numeric || false ? 'right' : 'left'}
      >
        <span>{label}</span>
      </TableCell>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { classes, columns, ...tableProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <AutoSizer>
        {({ height, width }) => (
          <Table height={height} width={width} {...tableProps} rowClassName={this.getRowClassName}>
            {columns.map(({ dataKey, ...other }, index) => {
              return (
                <Column
                  key={dataKey}
                  headerRenderer={headerProps =>
                    this.headerRenderer({
                      ...headerProps,
                      columnIndex: index,
                    })
                  }
                  className={classes.flexContainer}
                  cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
                  dataKey={dataKey}
                  {...other}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Table>
        )}
      </AutoSizer>
    );
  }
}

MuiVirtualizedTable.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  columns: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
  headerHeight: PropTypes.number,
  onRowClick: PropTypes.func,
  rowHeight: PropTypes.number,
};

const VirtualizedTable = withStyles(styles)(MuiVirtualizedTable);

// ---

const sample = [
  ['Frozen yoghurt', 159, 6.0, 24, 4.0],
  ['Ice cream sandwich', 237, 9.0, 37, 4.3],
  ['Eclair', 262, 16.0, 24, 6.0],
  ['Cupcake', 305, 3.7, 67, 4.3],
  ['Gingerbread', 356, 16.0, 49, 3.9],
];

function createData(id, dessert, calories, fat, carbs, protein) {
  return { id, dessert, calories, fat, carbs, protein };
}

const rows = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 200; i += 1) {
  const randomSelection = sample[Math.floor(Math.random() * sample.length)];
  rows.push(createData(i, ...randomSelection));
}

function ReactVirtualizedTable() {
  return (
    <Paper style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}>
      <VirtualizedTable
        rowCount={rows.length}
        rowGetter={({ index }) => rows[index]}
        columns={[
          {
            width: 200,
            label: 'Dessert',
            dataKey: 'dessert',
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Calories\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'calories',
            numeric: true,
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Fat\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'fat',
            numeric: true,
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Carbs\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'carbs',
            numeric: true,
          },
          {
            width: 120,
            label: 'Protein\u00A0(g)',
            dataKey: 'protein',
            numeric: true,
          },
        ]}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}

export default ReactVirtualizedTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [react-virtualized tables](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md) it supports a rowRenderer prop. You'll probably also need to add in an empty column in the header or it'll be misaligned.